# Why does "install" in this node.js code do an unexpected identifier error?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am currently trying to fix an error in some node.js code and the error says "Unexpected indentifier"
I use repl.it to make this code and it's only a single line.
I tried nothing and instantly contacted Nam on Discord.
The code is `npm install discord.js`.

Comment: Are you using the `npm` as javascript? It is meant to be used in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install` is a command you use in the terminal, not in your Javascript code.

You first add Discord.js to your project by typing `npm install discord.js` in the terminal, and then you can access the module in your Javascript code through `const Discord = require('discord.js')`.

Please read about how to get started with Discord.js on their [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js).